# Is there a reason to keep test dependencies in the :development group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a clear reason to have test dependencies in the `:development` group in a fully dockerized local environment?

I understand why have the test dependencies in the `:development, :test groups` without Docker, but in a dockerized environment, where you have different containers with proper environment variables, should this still be the case?

Comment: The answer is probally yes - some gems like `rspec-rails` need to be in the development group as well in order for the generators to work. That configuration also has to live somewhere and placing it in the Gemfile is the accepted way and most likely a lot less error prone then some hacky solution based on env vars.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few test specific gems I absolutely *love* having in my development environment.

`rspec-rails`: This provides me with generators to gen tests

`pry`/`pry-rails`/any other variant: This is essential to testing/dev debug

`factory_bot`: This is amazing to be able to open a dev rails console, add a few factories for test data, then hit the dev web side to see that data live

Overall, if you want to use any of these gems when debugging on the `development` web side, then yes... Include them in your dev group!

Answer (score 0):

For Rspec gem I am quoting the [official documentation:](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#configure)

> Adding it to the :development group is not strictly necessary, but without it, generators and rake tasks must be preceded by RAILS_ENV=test.